# modal content and tabs content bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

На одной странице у меня находится `tabs content`, в котором в одной из вкладок есть кнопка, вызывающая `modal content`.
Когда я нажимаю на кнопку, появляется `modal` и сразу пропадает `tab` с той вкладкой на которой была нажата кнопка.
При закрытии `modal`, `tab` не возвращается.
Через дебагер я вижу, что на `tab` наложился стиль `display:none;`.

Как этого избежать?

Еще если я вызываю окно через ссылку в таблице, которая в той же вкладке что и кнопка, то у меня вызывается `modal большой`(так и должно быть) и вместе с анимацией развертывания развертывается и `tab`.
Табы переключаю без скриптов.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab_view">
  <li class="active"><a href="#active_card" data-toggle="tab">Активные карточки</a></li>
  <li><a href="#deactive" data-toggle="tab">Архив</a></li>
  <li><a href="#statistics" data-toggle="tab">Статистика</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab_viewContent">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="active_card">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Активные карточки</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-5">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary put_notebook" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notebook_modal"><i class="icon-save"></i>Выдать ноутбук</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            .... .... ....
            <div id="notebook_modal" class="modal" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Без кода сложно разобраться.

Comment: добавил........

Comment: проблем быть не должно, [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/n8aLeee1/).
[Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: у меня modal динамический и обрабатывается через
  
 `$(".put_notebook").click(function () {
        console.log("add_event");
        //var split_class=$(this).attr("class").split(' ')[0];
     
        var url = "modal/";
        $(".modal-content").load(url)
    });`. 
А если статика как в примере то все работает. но мне нужна динамика.